# Getting "Invalid options provided" when running "yarn affected-depgraph"

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I'm creating an nx workspace to understand how it works, for that I followed the [getting started on the nrwl website](https://nrwl.io/nx) :

```
yarn global add @nrwl/schematics
create-nx-workspace myworkspace
```

Then I created a library and two different apps using the same library. I can get the both apps started with a `ng serve appName`.

I wanted to test the nx default scripts in the `package.json` but with no success :

```
ibenjelloun@COMPUTER MINGW64 /s/tmp/myworkspace (master)
$ yarn affected:dep-graph
yarn run v1.7.0
$ ./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:dep-graph
Invalid options provided
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Is there something to do to get these scripts working ? What did I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually stupid of mine, all the `affected:*` scripts are related to git changes, to do actions on uncommitted changes for example :

- `affected:apps -uncommitted` : prints the apps that are affected by the uncommited changes.
- `affected:build -uncommitted` : builds the apps that are affected by the uncommited changes.
- `affected:e2e -uncommitted` : run e2e tests for the apps that are affected by the uncommited changes.
- `affected:test -uncommitted` : run tests for the apps that are affected by the uncommited changes.
- `affected:dep-graph -uncommitted` : will get a graph similare to `dep-graph` script, with difference that affected apps and libs by the uncommited changes would have a different color.

My test project was not on a git repository.